# React cannot use URLs with more than one slash in Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently studying React with manual setup (not using Create-react-app).

I used Webpack and Babel.

After installing 'react-router-dom,' I tried to use URLs with more than one slash for the path attribute in  element. For example, "/contact/add"

However, it only returns a blank page with 404 error.

(Btw, it works perfectly when I use only one slash)

I looked around other stackoverflow posts and found that it's an issue with a "client-side" problem.

So, is there any method to handle this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any re-routing code in your `AddContact` component?